# convert list of Rdata into dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rdata

I have 1000 lists saved as Rdata all saved in one directory.
Each list has the same name, has 5 items and looks like this:

list.hv_Amono_volume

```
[[1]]
[1] 1.059246

[[2]]
[1] 1.047688

[[3]]
[1] 10.70799

[[4]]
[1] 10.30472

[[5]]
[1] 2.53379
```

When first storing the files in my directory I had given each file a unique name ie.: 
1_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata,

2_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata,

3_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata ... 1000_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata

I have loaded all 1000 Rdata files as follows:

```
 temp =list.files(path="mydirectory",pattern="*_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata")
```

but now I don't know how to extract the data from this list, obviously 'temp' gives me this

```
[1] "1_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"     "10_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"     
[3] "100_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"  "1000_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"
[5] "101_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"  "102_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata" 
[7] "103_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"  "104_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata" 
[9] "105_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"  "106_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"
```

[11] "107_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"  "108_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata" 
   [13] "109_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"  "11_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"
   [15] "110_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata"  "111_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata" ...

So I now need to know how to extract the data from the list and to bind it to a dataframe with 1000 columns which looks like this:

```
1          2         ... 1000
1.059246   1.044808      1.046917
1.047688   1.046857      1.036242
10.70799   10.70204      10.0781
10.30472   9.319236      10.29681
2.53379    2.430255      2.482879
```

I have tried playing around with this
    named.list <- lapply(temp,load)

and this

```
sapply(Amono_list.hv,  function(x) load(x, .GlobalEnv), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

but I am honestly very lost and not getting anywhere so your help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#This may work 
do.call(cbind,mget(paste0(1:1000,"_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand")))

#Edit: as per comments
```

Example:

```
x1<-as.list(1:3)
x2<-as.list(4:6)
save(x1,file="mydata1.RData") 
save(x2,file="mydata2.RData") 
tem<-list.files(pattern="*.RData")
str(tem)
 chr [1:2] "mydata1.RData" "mydata2.RData"
kk<-lapply(tem,load)
List of 2
 $ : chr "x1"
 $ : chr "x2"

do.call(cbind,lapply(1:2,function(i)get(kk[[i]])))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1    4   
[2,] 2    5   
[3,] 3    6
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it tells me it caanot find the value for '1_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand'.

Comment: You need to first check when you type `1_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand` or   `1000_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand` in the console, does it give you the output?. If you see that, this code will work.`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't give me the output. I cannot figure out how to access the data in that list. I know it is there because I have loaded individual files and can look at them in the console with 'list.hv_Amono_volume'. this is the same whether I load '1_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand' or '1000_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand'.

Comment: In that case you need to first load all files in `temp` .

Comment: Ok, I have loaded all files. But how do I tell do.call to get the files from temp. I am very suspicious that I am completely overlooking something here, because I just don't get it! Really sorry. btw. str(temp) gives me chr [1:1000] "1_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata" . "10_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata" ... Does that seem right?

Comment: temp <- list.files(path="directory",pattern="*_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata")

do.call(cbind,lapply(1:1000,function(i)get(temp[i])))
 gives me this error:Error in get(temp[i]) : 
  object '1_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata' not found

Comment: You need to load each file of temp before you apply `do.call`. Let me update the solution.

Comment: Please check the answer. It assumes that when you load each file, the first one is the one with 1, the second one is with 2,and the last one 1000.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. `get()` didn't work for me in `do.call()` so I used this loop instead.      `res <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol =1000)

    for(i in 1:length(kk)){
      res[,i] <- unlist(get(kk[[i]]))
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This is untested. The idea is that when you load() a file, there are R objects that get loaded. For this example, I'm assuming each file only contains a single R object. In the getList() function, we load the file into a temporary environment, read it, find the name, and return the object (which is hopefully a list). Major assumption here is that there's only one object per file and it's a list. Then use sapply like you had tried...

```
temp <-list.files(path="mydirectory",pattern="*_list.hv_Amono_volume_rand.Rdata")
e <- new.env()
getList <- function(filename){
  rm(list = ls(all = TRUE), envir=e) 
  load(filename, envir=e)
  # get name of thing you loaded... assuming just one thing there...
  theName <- ls(envir=e)[1]
  return(get(theName))
}
df <- sapply(temp, function(x)cbind(getList(x)))
```

Comment: yes, each object is a list of length 5. But I have 1000 of those in one file in my directory. Do you mean by filename the name of the file my R objects are stored in? and by 'theName' do you mean the name of the Rdata object once I have loaded it? Because that name is the same for the 1000 objects.

Comment: yes, filename is the name of the files... which should be stored in "temp". theName is the name of the object stored in the file. If you know what that object is, you can cut out that part of the funciton.